# Resizing google earth copyright information in api

Tags: javascript, api, google-earth-plugin

Im trying to decrease the size of the copyright information as it obstructs the view a little as the google earth api plugin is very small. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anyway to get ahold of that part of the screen.  The last time I looked, Google hadn't defined a method to do this.  They used to have user agreements that specifically forbade this.

Comment: They still do - 8.5 Proprietary Rights Notices. You agree that you will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) that may be affixed to or provided through the Service. Where such notices are not affixed within the Service, you agree to display such notices according to the Maps APIs Documentation. see https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en

Comment: I dont want to remove it, just resize it because its bulky. might as well leave it due to copyright etc. cheers tho

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the copyright is Google's IPR. You can't mess with it.